# ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to

Tags: java, cuba-platform

I am using service in CUBA-FRAMEWORK to do some data manipulation and getting the following error:

```
ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to com.company.gms.entity.ProductionPlanResource
```

the error is originated in the following line of code:

```
matReqDate = DateUtils.addDays((Date)planQuery.getFirstResult().getStartDate(), daysOffset);
                                            }
```

additional codes around :

```
    Date reqShipDate = soline.getRequiredShipDate();
                                                Date matReqDate;
                                                TypedQuery<ProductionPlanResource> planQuery = persistence.getEntityManager()
                                                        .createQuery("select MIN(e.startDate) from mydb$ProductionPlanResource e " +
                                                                " where e.productionPlan.salesOrder.id = ?1 AND e.article.id = ?2", ProductionPlanResource.class);
                                                        planQuery.setParameter(1, soline.getSalesOrder().getId()).setParameter(2, article.getId());

                                                if (planQuery.getResultList().size() > 0) {

                                                    matReqDate = DateUtils.addDays((Date)planQuery.getFirstResult().getStartDate(), daysOffset);
                                                }
```

I tried this, but didn't help

```
java.sql.Date startDate = (java.sql.Date)planQuery.getFirstResult().getStartDate();
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the type of planQuery.getFirstResult().getStartDate() ? Is it a java.util.Date ? or a java.sql.Date ?. Can you print getClass().getName() and see what is output ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `TypedQuery` is expected to return a `ProductionPlanResource` but looking at the query itself, it gives back `MIN(e.startDate)` which seems to be a date instead of a `ProductionPlanResource`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells You that there is a Date which is cast to ProductionPlanResource. That is the problem.

```
TypedQuery<ProductionPlanResource> planQuery =  ...
...select MIN(e.startDate) from ...
```

The result is a Date and the TypedQuery is for type ProductionPlanResource.

Try change to:

```
TypedQuery<Date> planQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to .getTime() and then convert, since long value is read by both, java and sql date.